# std::tie for C++17 struct operator<?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following C++17 struct:

```
struct S {
   M1 m1; M2 m2; M3 m3;

   bool operator<(const S& that) const { return tie() < that.tie(); }

   auto tie() const { return std::tie(m1,m2,m3); }
};
```

Is this correct?  Will `S::tie` return a tuple of references to the members, or will it take a copy?  Will auto deduce the correct type (a tuple of references) ?  Does the constness do the right thing?

(The examples that I've seen make two calls to std::tie and don't factor out into a seperate member function like this.  Wondering / suspicious if there is a reason for that.)

Comment: `std::tie` returns _"...A std::tuple object containing lvalue references...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: @RichardCritten: Right, but if you look further down that page they call it twice in the example in `operator<`.  Will it work as I've done it above factoring out into member function?  I guess I'm just weirded-out by the fact that they didn't do it that way in example.

Comment: member function is better - see DRY rule. So your version is better, less bug prone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes, although that may depend on what you are intending to do.

> Will S::tie return a tuple of references to the members

Yes.

> or will it take a copy?

No. This is easy to verify by trying it with a non-copyable type.

> Will auto deduce the correct type (a tuple of references) ?

Yes.

---

This won't be necessary nor useful anymore in C++20 with the introduction of defaulted comparison operators.

Comment: The tie technique can be used for more than just comparison operators.

Comment: *"This won't be necessary nor useful anymore in C++20 with the introduction of defaulted comparison operators."* It seems that `std:tie` is still the way to go in some [common scenarios](https://godbolt.org/z/d1v86jh6h), e.g. when wanting to omit certain data-member(s) from a defaulted comparison.